# How to call C++ API with numpy array of user defined structs via pybind11

Tags: python, c++, numpy, pybind11

I have went through documentation and searched a lot on internet but couldn't find any resolution. Here is relevant code snippet

```
struct Ohlc {
    double open, high, low, close;
    int volume;
};

using array_dtype = Ohlc;

void calculate_ema_pyarray(const py::array_t<const array_dtype,
     py::array::c_style | py::array::forcecast> array) {
 // DO something with array
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(ema_calculator_pybind11, m) {
  // optional module docstring
  m.doc() = "pybind11 plugin for ema calculations";

  py::class_<Ohlc>(m, "Ohlc")
      .def(py::init<>())
      .def_readwrite("open", &Ohlc::open)
      .def_readwrite("high", &Ohlc::high)
      .def_readwrite("low", &Ohlc::low)
      .def_readwrite("close", &Ohlc::close);

     PYBIND11_NUMPY_DTYPE(Ohlc, open, high, low, close);

  m.def("calculate_ema", &calculate_ema_pyarray,
     "Calculates EMA for given input");
}
```

Below is the error I get while using it in python

```
>>> from ema_calculator_pybind11 import *
>>> import numpy as np
>>> calculate_ema(np.array([Ohlc()]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: calculate_ema(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: numpy.ndarray[ema_calculator_pybind11.Ohlc]) -> None

Invoked with: array([<ema_calculator_pybind11.Ohlc object at 0x7f926d284670>],
      dtype=object)
```

Above works if I change array_dtype to build-in type, e.g. `using array_dtype = double;` or if I take only 1 object of `Ohlc` instead of an array.
Not sure if it's a missing feature or bug or quite likely something missing in my code. Please advise.

Comment: Did you try to create the array like this `np.array([Ohlc()], dtype=ema_calculator_pybind11.Ohlc)` instead?

Comment: Did you try to use only small letters, e.g. `ohlc` instead of `Ohlc`? I once had a problem similar to that and that drove me crazy when using `pybind11`...

Comment: same error with `dtype=ema_calculator_pybind11.Ohlc`. with ohlc error is ```NameError: name 'ohlc' is not defined```

Comment: Something new I came across which might be relevant here is that seems like the way I have defined and bound stuff above, numpy array consists of `objects` of `Ohlc`, which is basically a pointer/reference. What I really need on C++ side is what's called `structured/record` numpy array and python side code will require changes. But I still can't figure out how to correctly specify py bindings for that.

Answer (score 0):

See the section on assigning data to a structured array [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#assigning-data-to-a-structured-array). You can pass a list of tuples representing the value of each field in the dtype e.g.

```py
from ema_calculator_pybind11 import *
import numpy as np
calculate_ema(np.array([
    (1.0, 1.2, 0.9, 1.05, 100),
    (100.0, 150.0, 90.0, 100.0, 200)
], dtype=Ohlc))
```

numpy tries to assign to the individual fields, not the datatype itself.